# Data-loss safety of "cryptsetup luksOpen <root device>" between suspend and resume

Tags: arch-linux, disk-encryption, cryptsetup, mkinitcpio

I'm setting up suspend-to-disk and resume in an 2021.12.x Arch Linux install. My question is about safely (without data-loss) unlocking partitions when resuming.

Here is my configuration. The bootloader is grub 2.06, and I'm using a busybox-based initramfs. The relevant partitions are below. I'm not using LVM.

```
# partition  encrypted   mountpoint     decrypted volume name
- ---------  ---------   ----------     ---------------------
...
3 root           luks2   /              cryptroot
4 swap           luks2   [SWAP]         cryptswap
...
```

In `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` I've configured these hooks.

```
HOOKS=(base udev ... openswap openroot ... resume ... filesystems fsck)
```

I'm not using the built-in [encrypt](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/tree/packages/cryptsetup/trunk) hook. It can only unlock one device (typically only the root device which is specified in the `cryptdevice` kernel parameter), but I need to unlock the encrypted swap device, too. So instead of the encrypt hook I use two custom hooks: openswap and openroot. The openswap hook, in essence, runs: `cryptsetup luksOpen <swap device> cryptswap`
which prompts for a password. The openroot hook does the same for the root partition device: `cryptsetup luksOpen <root device> cryptroot`.

Next, the built-in resume hook [writes the swap device's major and minor numbers to `/sys/power/resume`](https://github.com/archlinux/mkinitcpio/blob/0a972cd/hooks/resume#L25-L28).

```
printf "$devmajor:$devminor" >/sys/power/resume
```

There are two scenarios at this point.

#### Scenario 1: If starting up after full shutdown

When starting the computer after a full shutdown, there is no hibernation image in the unlocked swap partition. There is nothing to resume from, so a regular boot occurs. The root partition has been unlocked by this point (by the openroot hook), so booting can proceed correctly.

No question of safety in this scenario.

#### Scenario 2: If starting up after suspend-to-disk

Earlier, when I would have initiated a suspend-to-disk, the root partition would have been in an unlocked and mounted state, and the hibernation image would have captured this state as is.  Now, after kernel uses this hibernation image to resume, the system will continue to use this (already) unlocked/mounted root partition device.

**This is where my question arises:**

I know it is bad to *`mount`* a device in between suspend and resume. For example, [kernel.org says](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/swsusp.html): "If you touch anything on disk between suspend and resume… …kiss your data goodbye." My configuration doesn't do this.

Is it similarly bad to `cryptsetup luksOpen` a device in between suspend and resume? Does `cryptsetup luksOpen` constitute touching (kernel.org terminology above) the disk? Recall that the initramfs openroot hook runs `cryptsetup luksOpen <root device> cryptroot` between suspend and resume.

If so, how does one handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, the `cryptsetup luksOpen` is a purely read-only operation. However simply the act of unlocking a block device, triggers dependencies such as udev rules, and this in turn might trigger auto assembly (for raid and lvm devices), which in turn creates more block devices, which in turn triggers more udev rules, etc.

So it's best to avoid the whole conundrum by running the hooks in the right order.

If the `resume` hook only needs the swap partition (i.e. there is no other swap device or swap file involved), `resume` should run straight after `openswap`, before `openroot`.

Otherwise your setup also gives a false sense of security, by asking for a root encryption password which is not required for resume at all and will end up being discarded by the resume anyway.

Unless you have code to stop execution, for a suspended system the `resume` hook should succeed even if you repeatedly enter the wrong passphrase for the `openroot` hook. So this is an easy way to verify that theory before changing the hook order.